# Attaching an android form to asp.net

Tags: android, mysql, asp.net, xml, json

I am creating an android application where i have a form which the user needs to fill up.
Then i want to send the values inserted to an asp.net page which catches the data and saves it to a database attached to that page and after the value gets inserted into the database the database sends a response to the android application.
Like 1 or 0 is send as a feedback
1 for successful data entry
0 for failure.

Can it be done if so how??
Please Help and Thank You.

Comment: yes you can, with `Json` or `XML` you can connect with server in android

Comment: can i get an example like a code or a website to learn more about this

Comment: if you search on google you can find useful tutorial, like [This](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/android.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is your android Code

```
public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/myexample.aspx");

try {
// Add your data
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("EmpID", "12345"));
 //keep adding like this
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SecondVariable", "12345"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

// Execute HTTP Post Request
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
InputStream is = entity.getContent();

//String RESPONSE FROM SERVER
 String whatIgotResponse= convertStreamToString(is);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
}


private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append((line + "\n"));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

In your ASPX page, your can retrive the data with

```
//all the nameValuePairs your have send
      string EmpID = Request.Form["EmpID"];

//now use your basic SQL Connection with the values to insert
     SQL........

// after the SQL Query you can use 
    Response.Write("Something Something");
```

Comment: i think this is not very good for start, with this i don't think so OP can find anything, i think for start OP need to learn AsyncTask and json then read your answer

Comment: I understood the android code but can you describe a bit more in case of the aspx page code!!!
Thank You for your help @MDMalik

Comment: @user3256491 are you still looking for the answer. Should I help you. Becz its quite a while so asking??

Comment: Yes i need help understanding the aspx part.
A demo will do or tutorial or anything to make me understand will do